# Linear Algebra Vector Polynomial and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was just wondering if the dimension of $P_4$. Does that mean that all the vector space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to four, has the dimension $4$?

Also if a set of vectors $(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$ is linear independent. And $M$ is a linear map then $M(v_1),M(v_2),\ldots,M(v_n)$ is linearly independent

Comment: I'm afraid a (single) "polynomial" doesn't have any dimension. And the output of a set of vectors "linearly transformed" is not a "linear map" either.

Comment: ok i edited the question

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to talk about the 'dimension' of a single polynomial, since dimension is a concept attached to vector spaces. We can talk about the *degree*, which is the highest power of the independent variable that shows up in the polynomial; then the set of polynomials with coefficients in a given field (e.g. the real or complex numbers) forms a vector space. If we consider the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$, then it's a vector space of dimension $n$, with basis given by $\{1, x, x^2, ..., x^n\}$.

It's not true that the image of a linearly independent set is linearly independent; just choose $M = 0$, for instance. Counterexamples can be found whenever $M$ maps from a space to a space of lower dimension.

If $M$ is assumed to be injective, then the image of a linearly independent set is still linearly independent; the proof is instructive, and left to the reader.

Comment: the first page of this link https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/S12/MAT217_Lecture_8.pdf shows that they are equal though. This is why im confused

Comment: @user123204 The first page says exactly what I did ('injective' and 'one-to-one' are synonyms). That assumption is critical.

Comment: Oh ok, so if does not say one-to-one linear independent set and only says linear independent set, you can't assume that it's one to one? and therefore it could be false?

Comment: @user123204 "One-to-one" is a property of functions, not a property of sets; so "one-to-one linear independent set" doesn't make sense. What the pdf says is that if $T$ is a one-to-one linear map and $A$ is a linearly independent set, then $T(A)$ is also linearly independent.